# tabulate one variable in a data.frame against all others using janitor::tabyl

Tags: r, janitor

**Data:**

| product | q1 | q2 | q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | NA |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | NA |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 9 | 6 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 | 4 | NA |

This is a small example, but my code loops through column q2 and when reaches q3 it shows
`Error: Selections can't have missing values.` Cant change Null values to 0 as it would change the mean.

**Code**

```
for(i in 2:ncol(dataset)){
  column<-names(dataset[i])
  count<-tabyl(dataset,dataset[,i],product,show_na = FALSE,show_missing_levels = FALSE) %>% adorn_percentages("col") %>% adorn_pct_formatting(digits=0)
  print(column)
  print(count)
}
```

Also, q1,q2 and so on are rankings of product based on the question, so the ranking scale is 1-9 but in the dataset there are some numbers of the scale not mentioned. Is there a way to show all the scale values even if its frequency is 0?

Comment: I revised your question a little to clarify it, I hope I interpreted it accurately.  There's often a more natural (to R) way to iterate than for-loops, and here your loop is sending a mix of vectors (`dataset[,i]`) and column names to `tabyl` when it needs either a single vector or a data.frame and two column names.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
x <- read.table(text = "product     q1  q2  q3
1   5   9   NA
1   6   7   NA
2   4   4   9
2   9   6   8
2   8   4   NA", header = TRUE)
```

To make tabyls showing your `product` variable against all other columns, you can first make the data "long", then use the functions you originally had:

```
x %>%
  pivot_longer(q1:q3, "q", "value") %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels = 1:9)) %>% # this is for your 1-9 scale
  tabyl(value, product, q, show_na = FALSE) %>%
  adorn_percentages("col") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>%
  adorn_title()
```

**Result**

```
$q1
       product    
 value       1   2
     1      0%  0%
     2      0%  0%
     3      0%  0%
     4      0% 33%
     5     50%  0%
     6     50%  0%
     7      0%  0%
     8      0% 33%
     9      0% 33%

$q2
       product    
 value       1   2
     1      0%  0%
     2      0%  0%
     3      0%  0%
     4      0% 67%
     5      0%  0%
     6      0% 33%
     7     50%  0%
     8      0%  0%
     9     50%  0%

$q3
       product    
 value       1   2
     1       -  0%
     2       -  0%
     3       -  0%
     4       -  0%
     5       -  0%
     6       -  0%
     7       -  0%
     8       - 50%
     9       - 50%
```

Comment: If anyone has a good approach to doing this with the data wide, rather than putting all of the variables into a single shared column, I'd love to see it.  Then it would be robust to the variables having different factor levels.

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked perfectly. But yea, like you said I do have variables with different factors like 1-9 and 1-5 which I forgot to mention.